# JMETER | Selenium WebDriver | Multiple threads are not running properly

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to run for 5 - 10 users using WebDriver Sampler in JMeter. I have configured Chrome Driver and provided WebDriver Sampler for code. When I am running for 1 user, it is running perfectly fine. But for multiple users, test is failing at some point where it is unable to locate some dropdowns. Only 1 thread is passed and others are getting failed. Is there any way to run for multiple threads in background?

[Structure of JMeter configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls5KT.png)

I have tried WebDriver Sampler for 5 - 10 users. It is passing for 1. Expecting the same behavior for other threads as well. Else, how to run the same code in Headless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't use Selenium for performance testing.**

Quote from [Selenium website](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/):

> Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.

Quote from [JMeter Plugins website](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/):

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/). Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So instead of trying to resolve your issue with multiple browsers I would rather recommend switching to HTTP protocol and [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

---

With regards to your questions itself:

- Make sure your computer has enough resources, for example [Firefox 114](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/114.0/system-requirements/) requires 1 CPU core and 2 GB or RAM per instance so if your machine has less than 24 GB of RAM I wouldn't recommend kicking off 10 browsers in parallel
- If "dropdowns" are not available immediately you might want to increase default [timeouts](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html) or use Selenium [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have increased the wait time and RAM is also more than 24GB, still out of 5 threads 3 gets failed as it is not able to locate the elements. As I am trying on .net application and APIs are not exposed. Is there any other way to do the performance testing?

Comment: If a browser can interact with the website then JMeter should also be able to. Try recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) and you will see.

Comment: I tried recording using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and it is working now. Able to run for 80 users now, Thanks